# Cannot create SqlLite database on target PC - fine on dev PC

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, vsto

I've made a VSTO addin for outlook, and it works fine in both release and debug modes on my development machine. Even if I manually delete all the build files and the sqllite database it creates everything from scratch the next time you launch outlook, and carries on as though nothing happened.

When I then install it on the target computer, it simply won't create a sqllite database file. It'll make the directory to put it in, tell me where it's going to put it, and then it just doesn't make the file. It then can't store what it's doing later on, and so just falls over. Unfortunately I copied the command to make the connection from a tutorial, and so don't know what to try!

My code is below:

```
Public Class ClsSqlLiteDatabase
 Public sub new ClsSqlLiteDatabase
  Try
        Dim sqlite_cmd As SQLiteCommand

        Dim dataFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\SBDR Toolbox\"

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(dataFolder)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dataFolder)
        End If

        Debug.WriteLine(dataFolder & "database.sqlite")

        ' create a new database connection:
        conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & dataFolder & "database.sqlite;Version=3;")


        ' open the connection:
        conn.Open()

        sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand()

        ' Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    [MyBids] (
    [pReference]     NVARCHAR(2048) NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [sReference]   NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
    [AM]  NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
    [CC]  NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
    [Customer]  NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
    [Vendor]   NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
    [Distributor]   NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
    [NDT]   NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)"

        ' Now lets execute the SQL ;-)
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch

        Debug.WriteLine("Could not initialise SQLLite Database")


    End Try
 End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you actually create the sql db file? You create your `SBDR Toolbox` which is simply the directory. Then you try to create a connection with the data source `dataFolder & database.sqlite`, but `database.sqlite` hasn't actually been created anywhere.

Comment: On the Dev machine the line `conn = New SQLiteConnection(...` creates the file if it's not present already - so I assumed it would on the target machine too?

Comment: Ok, I usually use `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile` after checking if file does not exist. But it does appear that the connection has the ability to create the file if it doesn't exist. Maybe you are running into a permissions issue in the Application Data folder

Comment: I could create the folder, so didn't think it was a permissions issue - having added the 'SQLiteConnection.CreateFile' line in I now have a 0 byte database file in the same place, but it remains at zero bytes even after the connection and table creation commands - I also can't add lines to it.
Having added `msgbox(ex.message)` to the `catch` section of the code I can now see it's missing `SQLite.interop.dll` - which appears to be in subfolders of my "release" directory, one for `x86` and one for `x64` - I'll make sure to add these to my installer

Comment: Everything now works. Lesson learnt - exception messages are there for a reason!